# Basic setup.py - include the shared library

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I am packaging a Python package with around 20 Python modules and one shared library[1]. I have create the following `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = "mypack",
    version = "1.0",
    author = "Bill Coder",
    author_email = "bill.coder@email.com",
    description = ("My Code"),
    packages=find_packages(),
    long_description="Long description",
    )
```

And the filesystem looks like this:

```
mypack/
   __init__.py
   sub_pack1/
      __init__.py
      module1.py
      module2.py
   sub_pack2
      __init__.py
      moduleA.py
      shared_library.so
```

I have tried the commands:

```
bash% python -m build --wheel
```

and

```
bash% python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

in both cases a wheel package is assembled but the shared library `mypack/subpack2/shared_library.so` is *not* included in the final product.

[1]: The shared library comes from `cythonize` on a pyx file. Ideally I would like to build the extension as part of the `setup.py`- but for now I settle for the more moderate ambition of an external build process and then packaging everything up into a package which I can install myself. The purpose of the package is just to serve as a temporary step between CI and target - the package will not be published beyond that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `include_package_data=True` to your setup.py.

You may need to include a `MANIFEST.in` file to your project root that points to the additional file:

```
include mypack/sub_pack2/shared_library.so
```

> more about this [here](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html)

Comment: Thank you. The `MANIFEST.in` was the solution. Adding `include_package_data=True` did not have any effect in my case.

Comment: ```include_package_data=True``` worked for me :) just had to also specify ```package_data={'': ['py_my_lib.so']},```